# ZSH character indicator invisible when using arrow keys

Tags: zsh

I recently switched to zsh and after some tweaking am quite happy with it, but I have one problem: When I'm using the arrow keys to go back/forward a few characters the indicator that shows you on which character you are on is not visible until I stop using the arrow keys. Could anyone tell me where I can change this behavior? Thanks

Comment: This may depend on the terminal emulator. Which one are you using and did/could you try with another?

Comment: I'm using gnome she'll. Might look for another one that I like then!